# How to avoid promise already under evaluation warning for setting default argument as a function of another argument

Tags: r, parameter-passing, lazy-evaluation

I've read the other answers for issues related to the "promise already under evaluation" warning, but I am unable to see how they can help me avoid this problem.

Here I have a function that for one method, takes a default argument value that is a function of another value.

```
myfun <- function(x, ones = NULL) {
    UseMethod("myfun")
}


myfun.list <- function(x, ones = NA) {
    data.frame(x = x[[1]], ones)
}

ones <- function(x) {
    rep(1, length(x))
}
```

So far, so good:

```
myfun(list(letters[1:5]))
##   x ones
## 1 a   NA
## 2 b   NA
## 3 c   NA
## 4 d   NA
## 5 e   NA
```

But when I define another method that sets the default for the `ones` argument as the function `ones(x)`, I get an error:

```
myfun.character <- function(x, ones = ones(x)) {
    myfun(as.list(x), ones)
}

myfun(letters[1:5])
## Error in data.frame(x = x[[1]], ones) : 
##  promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?
```

For various reasons, I need to keep the argument name the same as the function name (for `ones`).  **How can I force evaluation of the argument within `my fun.character`?**   I also need this to work (which it does):

```
myfun(letters[1:5], 1:5)
##   x ones
## 1 a    1
## 2 a    2
## 3 a    3
## 4 a    4
## 5 a    5
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One would need to look deep into R's (notorious) environments to understand exactly, where it tries to find `ones`. The problem is located in the way supplied and default arguments are evaluated within a function. You can see [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-November/180902.html) link from the R manual and also an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982223/an-error-i-cant-understand-promise-already-under-evaluation).

The easy solution is to tell R where to look for it. It will save you the hassle. In your case that's the global environment.

Changing method `myfun.character` to tell it to look for `ones` in the global environment:

```
myfun.character <- function(x, ones = get('ones', envir = globalenv())(x)) {

  myfun(as.list(x), ones)

}
```

will be enough here.

Out:

```
myfun(letters[1:5])
#  x ones
#1 a    1
#2 a    1
#3 a    1
#4 a    1
#5 a    1

myfun(letters[1:5], 1:5)
#  x ones
#1 a    1
#2 a    2
#3 a    3
#4 a    4
#5 a    5
```

Comment: That pointed me to a solution: for the package where this example represents the problem, to use the equivalent of `package::ones(x)` in the `myfun.character` function signature. Thanks! Just to shorten it, however, Is there any way to force evaluation of the package::ones(x) within myfun.character, using the original function signature from the question?

Comment: using `::` will point R to the package's namespace environment, so you are essentially telling R where to look at to find the function. Using `::` is the right way, I don't think there is a way to shorten it in this case.